# Combining LUIS and Qna via Node.js

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I would like to build a ChatBot using Microsoft Service LUIS and QnA. I was searching online at some Microsoft github projects in which the two elements were supposed to be combined. However, the source code does not exist anymore. 
I would like to use Node.js and it would be great if I could get any examples on this.

Could anybody help me out on this?

Cheers,
Andi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure BOT Framework, Integrate QnA Maker with LUIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812965/azure-bot-framework-integrate-qna-maker-with-luis)

Comment: Looks like the same question is arriving almost every day. Did you tried to implement LUIS first? Then have a look on how to use QnA, and combine both by making the call of QnA from LUIS's None intent